# Resolvido - Reescrever HTTP para HTTPS com Let's Encrypt

Tags: php, htaccess, mvc

Tenho o arquivo .htaccess com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Ao carregar a página preciso que já seja exibido o https://...

Mas somente quando clico nos links internos é exibido o certificado.

Não entendo muito bem destas instruções. Sei que o site utiliza a estrutura MVC, por isso esta configuração no .htaccess

Possuo também um config.php, que contém algumas configurações e a seguinte linha:

```
define( 'HOME_URI', 'http://meusite.com/' );
```

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Answer (score -2):

adicione as seguintes linhas abaixo do rewriteEngine ON e abaixo das suas rewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

ficando assim o codigo

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

isso vai fazer com que toda requisição http seja redirecionada para https

Comment: Obrigado Gilmar pela contribuição.Mas a pagina acusa o seguinte erro: "Redirecionamento em excesso por meusite.com
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Então tente no lugar daquelas duas linhas, essas duas:

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seudominio.com.br/$1 [R,L]

O editor aqui não deixa dar enter, mais cada Rewrite, é uma linha

Comment: meu amigo, o negócio ficou punk aqui. Ele reescreveu a URL com o caminho do servidor: http://wacabinetsorlando.com/var/www/html/wacabinetsorlando.com/web/wacabinetsorlando.com/

Comment: entrei em contato com o Uol Hosts, e o problema estava na configuração deles!